# python setuptools and easy_install numpy

Tags: python, numpy, setuptools

Doesn't `setuptools` use `easy_install` to get the additional dependencies you specify in a `setup.py`? I'm asking because say I have a `setup.py` and in the `install_requires = ["numpy"]`. Now if I run `python setup.py install`, it gives a error:

```
_configtest.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
_configtest.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//cciDxELX.out
_configtest.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
_configtest.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

However if I run `easy_install numpy` works. What could cause this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kind of error you're receiving is usually because you don't have the Python development package installed. If you're using an Ubuntu based distribution, go to Synaptic, and search for `python-dev` (the name may not be 100% accurate, do a little browsing there).

It could be that `easy_install` works with prebuilt stuff.

Comment: I'm on MacOS. And the problem is that it only give these errors when it is listed as a install_requires from the setup.py. If i just go easy_install numpy from command line the error is gone.