# Installing numpy as a dependency with setuptools

Tags: python, numpy, setuptools, python-2.7

This might be a follow up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6623973/572616) one.

I am using [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to install a package of mine. As a dependency I have listed [numpy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy). I am using Python2.7 and when I do

```
python setup.py install
```

with this `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name = "test_pack", install_requires = ["numpy"])
```

I end up with this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
```

What do I need to do in order to include `numpy` as a dependency and install it without having `python-dev` installed?

---

The complete output of `python setup.py install`:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to test_pack.egg-info/requires.txt
writing test_pack.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to test_pack.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to test_pack.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'test_pack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'test_pack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/test_pack
copying build/lib/test_pack/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/test_pack
copying build/lib/test_pack/mod.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/test_pack
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/test_pack/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/test_pack/mod.py to mod.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying test_pack.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying test_pack.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying test_pack.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying test_pack.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying test_pack.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/test_pack-0.0.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing test_pack-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
Copying test_pack-0.0.0-py2.7.egg to /home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding test-pack 0.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_pack-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for test-pack==0.0.0
Searching for numpy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
Reading http://numpy.scipy.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=1369&package_id=175103
Reading http://numeric.scipy.org
Best match: numpy 1.6.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.zip#md5=462c22b8eb221c78ddd51de98fbb5979
Processing numpy-1.6.1.zip
Running numpy-1.6.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-AoFmdV/numpy-1.6.1/egg-dist-tmp-JH1j2R
non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
Could not locate executable g77
Found executable /opt/solstudio12.2/bin/f77
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
Found executable /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/073/bin/intel64/ifort
Could not locate executable lf95
Could not locate executable pgf90
Could not locate executable pgf77
Found executable /opt/solstudio12.2/bin/f90
Found executable /opt/solstudio12.2/bin/f95
Could not locate executable fort
_configtest.c:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
_configtest.o: In function `main':
/tmp/easy_install-AoFmdV/numpy-1.6.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
_configtest.c:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
_configtest.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
_configtest.o: In function `main':
/tmp/easy_install-AoFmdV/numpy-1.6.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
_configtest.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue, tracked on [`numpy/numpy #2434`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2434).

I found a workaround for this: add `numpy` to `setup_requires`. Having it in both `setup_requires` and `install_requires` seems to work fine with the most recent version of `setuptools`.

So, your `setup.py` should look something like

```
setup(
    # Your setup specific stuff here
    setup_requires=["numpy"],  # Just numpy here
    install_requires=["numpy"],  # Add any of your other dependencies here
)
```

Comment: Adding numpy to `setup_requires` was not enough. I also had to run `python setup.py unstall` twice to install numpy successfully, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605927/why-doesnt-setup-requires-work-properly-for-numpy

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have access to a binary distribution (pre-compiled/built) for numpy, you'll have to have the python headers available as it needs them to build numpy. This is why most package managers come with pre-compiled versions of these packages. For example you can `apt-get install python-numpy`, link that into your virtualenv, and when you try to install your program with `install_requires=['numpy']` it should see that it's already installed.

Comment: Isn't there a way to tell `setuptools` to build `numpy` before installing it? Building and installing `numpy` on its own works perfectly...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. From your pasted output it **is** attempting to build numpy.

Comment: Right, but I am able to build and install `numpy` downloading it on my own (not with `setuptools`). Only if I try to build and install it with `setuptools` it breaks.

Comment: Are you passing special parameters to it when you build it on your own? setuptools just tries to run `python setup.py install` I believe.

Comment: I simply do `python setup.py build && python setup.py install` in the unpacked `numpy` archive. And I cannot confirm that setuptools only tried to tun `python setup.py install`. If I only do `python setup.py install` in the fresh unpacked archive it also builds and installs correctly.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to run `bdist_egg`. What I would recommend is to just install it yourself, then the package that requires it will not attempt to install it again. Otherwise hopefully someone else can give you a better answer on how to coax setuptools into running the correct sequence of commands for numpy!

Comment: There appears to be a difference between your standard environment and that used during the setuptools installation of your package. For example, not only are the Python header files not found, neither is the Fortran compiler (required, since some Numpy algorithms are in Fortran)

Answer (score 2):

To install `numpy` the setuptools will download the package and compile it from source. However, there are some prerequisites to compile `numpy`, you can check it [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html#prerequisites).

```
_configtest.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

this error indicates that at least you do not have python-dev package installed(if you are using ubuntu/debian).