# Installing numpy as a dependency in setup.py

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having troubles with distributing a package. I want to install numpy 1.8.0 as a dependency in my setup.py. (Ubuntu 12.04)

```
install_requires=['pandas ==0.12.0','numpy ==1.8.0']
```

This might be an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710918/installing-numpy-as-a-dependency-with-setuptools) question. What they have said here is about installing the `python-dev`. I tried followings.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev   

sudo apt-get install python-gevent
```

Even after installing it, still the same error is there. Any help is appreciated.

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel
```

Comment: Tried installing **python-devel**? `sudo apt-get install python-devel`

Comment: From `apt-cache show python-dev`: „This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 Python version (currently v2.7)“. There are several `python*-dev` packages. Make sure you have the one which fits your python version.

Comment: @Akash : Yes, still getting the error..:(

Comment: I answered a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27253640/1306923 Does this workaround work for you?